# How to integrate websocket with emberjs?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, websocket, ember.js

I'm learning and building emberjs app with rails. 
In this app, I want the data to be pushed rather than polled to the client app.

For.e.g. the following snippet at http://awardwinningfjords.com/2011/12/27/emberjs-collections.html

```
// Setup a global namespace for our code.
Twitter = Em.Application.create({

  // When everything is loaded.
  ready: function() {

    // Start polling Twitter
    setInterval(function() {
      Twitter.searchResults.refresh();
    }, 2000);

    // The default search is empty, let's find some cats.
    Twitter.searchResults.set("query", "cats");

    // Call the superclass's `ready` method.
    this._super();
  }
});
```

It polls twitter API, but my question is how to make an EmberJS app that uses a WebSocket connection to update its state?

Answer (score 15):

You have to implement a DS.Adapter that understands how to handle WebSockets. Here is an simple example:

```
var SOCKET      = 'ws://localhost:9090/some-websocket';

var ID          = 'uuid';

var FIND        = 'find';
var FIND_MANY   = 'findMany';
var FIND_QUERY  = 'findQuery';
var FIND_ALL    = 'findAll';

/**
* Implementation of WebSocket for DS.Store
*/
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({

    revision: 4,

    adapter: DS.Adapter.create({

        socket: undefined,

        requests: undefined,

        send: function(action, type, data, result) {
            /* Specific to your web socket server side implementation */
            var request = {
                "uuid": generateUuid(),
                "action": action,
                "type": type.toString().substr(1),
                "data": data
            };
            this.socket.send(JSON.stringify(request));
            /* So I have access to the original request upon a response from the server */
            this.get('requests')[request.uuid] = request;
            return request;
        },

        find: function (store, type, id) {
            this.send(FIND, type, id);
        },

        findMany: function (store, type, ids, query) {
            this.send(FIND_MANY, type, ids);
        },

        findQuery: function (store, type, query, modelArray) {
            this.send(FIND_QUERY, type, query, modelArray).modelArray = modelArray;
        },

        findAll: function (store, type) {
            this.send(FIND_ALL, type);
        },

        /* Also implement:
         * createRecord & createRecords
         * updateRecord & updateRecords
         * deleteRecord & deleteRecords
         * commit & rollback
         */

        init: function () {

            var context = this;

            this.set('requests', {});

            var ws = new WebSocket(SOCKET);

            ws.onopen = function () {

            };

            ws.onmessage = function(event) {
                var response = JSON.parse(event.data);
                var request = context.get('requests')[response.uuid];

                switch (request.action) {
                    case FIND:
                        App.store.load(type, response.data[0]);
                        break;
                    case FIND_MANY:
                        App.store.loadMany(type, response.data);
                        break;
                    case FIND_QUERY:
                        request.modelArray.load(response.data);
                        break;
                    case FIND_ALL:
                        App.store.loadMany(type, response.data);
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw('Unknown Request: ' + request.action);
                }

                /* Cleanup */
                context.get('requests')[response.uuid] = undefined;
            };

            ws.onclose = function () {

            };

            this.set('socket', ws);
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the basic adapter. But is it really necessary to write down all for just the web-socket? I mean that there ain't anything thats in emberjs?

Comment: As far as I can tell Ember has a bultin REST implementation but not a WebSockets one for DS.Adapter (which is why I rolled my own).

Comment: Have you rolled it out or packaged up somewhere or github?

Comment: No I haven't. It's still very much a work in progress and is specific to the server-side web-socket implementation we are working with. I haven't put much thought into implementing something against a generic API similar to how Ember's REST implementation was done.

Comment: Doesn't those `find...()` functions have to return an array or something? How do you handle the asynchronous dataflow via web sockets?

Answer (score 3):

I actually was playing around with the code from that article a few days ago. Keep the handle bar template the same, and use the following code. Obviously, this all depends on what JSON you're passing through the socket. The following code is tried and tested with ntwitter for node.

```
Twitter = Em.Application.create({
    ready: function() {
        var socket = io.connect();
        socket.on('message', function(json) {
            Twitter.searchResults.addTweet(Twitter.Tweet.create(JSON.parse(json)));
        });

        this._super();
    }
});

//Model
Twitter.Tweet = Em.Object.extend();

//Collection
Twitter.searchResults = Em.ArrayController.create({
    content:    [],
    _idCache:   {},

    addTweet: function(tweet) {
        var id = tweet.get("id");
        if (typeof this._idCache[id] === "undefined") {
            this.pushObject(tweet);
            this._idCache[id] = tweet.id;
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: So to run that, I think I've to have the nodejs installed? Will that be a dependency for that simple emberjs with web-socket enabled?

Comment: Yeah, this is client side code to interface with the socket.io library on node, but i assume it'll be very similar to plugin to a different socket powered backend.

Answer (score 1):

With websockets you are observing for socket events. When an event is triggered you handle that event (if appropriate) and then set your values.

Looking at your code you would you would observe Socket.onmessage. If the message contains what you are looking for then call refresh.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still confused. Does Socket.onmessage is implemented in Ember? Or something else do I need to know. Some code would be rather helpful!