# Ember-Data Websocket Adapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I need to create a websocket adapter for working with Ember-data, and came across this example in stackoverflow.

[How to integrate websocket with emberjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535007/how-to-integrate-websocket-with-emberjs)

But with all this stuff I'm reading about Ember using promises, I'm wondering whether code such as that shown in the example would work with the most recent versions of Ember & Ember-data.  Do all the methods in the adapters (e.g., find, findAll, createRecord, etc.) have to return promises?

Conceptually, I think I understand what promises are designed to do, but I don't really know how to use it.  Can someone knowledgeable please explain?

Comment: You will need to use **pushPayload** to load the data from websocket into ember-data. see  **https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/1468#issuecomment-27432110**. A better explanation on **pushPayload** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373446/how-to-hit-non-rest-endpoints-with-ember-data-1-0-beta. A video on promises by an emberjs core member - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g5CSaK3HqVA